# Add alert if using firefox

Tags: alert

I have an issue on my webpage, it's not running properly for some reason in firefox.

How do I alert Firefox users only with an alert/dialogue that there is an issue using their browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following thing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    const isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    if (isFirefox){
        alert('Danger!');  
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that could help you!